# Как отключить button с картинкой, чтобы она не становилась черно-белой?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

У меня имеется несколько button, которые я создаю в коде и ставлю на них картинки. Далее я их отключаю через `pressedButton.Enabled = false;`
Но при этом картинки становятся черно-белыми. Есть какой-то способ, чтобы при отключении кнопки картинки оставались цветными?

Comment: Откуда взялись картинки в кнопке?

Comment: @aepot через button.Image

Comment: Ну это стандартное поведение для кнопки, насколько мне известно, его не переопределить не используя наследование, можно только создать свой юзерконтрол на основе кнопки, и научить его работать как вам надо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно ввести флаг обозначающий, должна ли отрабатывать кнопка или нет, и оперировать уже им.

```
public bool isButtonClickable { get; set; }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isButtonClickable) return;
}
```

И, тогда, если этот флаг выставить в true, клик по кнопке не будет вызывать никакой логики. К этому же флагу можно привязать изменение фокуса, что бы кнопка не получала "синюю границу" при клике на неё.

```
private void Button1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isButtonClickable)
    {
        // this - форма. Эта строка снимет фокус с кнопки
        this.ActiveControl = null;
    }
}
```

Или. Как компромис, можно выставлять `...Enabled = true` и `...Enabled = false`
на событиях `MouseEnter` и `MouseLeave` что бы показать пользователю что кнопка не работает, пока мышь находится на этой самой кнопке. А когда мышь не на кнопке, то кнопка будет выглядеть ровно как и обычная, с цветной картинкой.